# megatimer настройка таймера в коде

Tags: javascript

Есть сайт https://megatimer.ru/ на котором я настраиваю дату окончания таймера и сам таймер, и есть файл megatimer.js в котором и прописан код окончания таймера и всё остальное(но я немогу его найти(может даже проблема не в файле а в чем то другом), нужна помощь в этом).
Заказчик должен самостоятельно настраивать таймер, как это сделать? (мне нужно просто сказать ему строку)

Вот код таймера

```js
(function() {
  var _id = "65dc1667e4a669bb6a36cf929343c29d";
  while (document.getElementById("timer" + _id)) _id = _id + "0";
  document.write("<div id='timer" + _id + "' style='min-width:488px;height:147px;'></div>");
  var _t = document.createElement("script");
  _t.src = "https://megatimer.ru/timer/timer.min.js";
  var _f = function(_k) {
    var l = new MegaTimer(_id, {
      "view": [1, 1, 0, 0],
      "type": {
        "currentType": "1",
        "params": {
          "usertime": true,
          "tz": "3",
          "utc": 1563055200000
        }
      },
      "design": {
        "type": "plate",
        "params": {
          "round": "10",
          "background": "solid",
          "background-color": "#ffffff",
          "effect": "flipchart",
          "space": "12",
          "separator-margin": "28",
          "number-font-family": {
            "family": "Arial"
          },
          "number-font-size": "97",
          "number-font-color": "#000000",
          "padding": "24",
          "separator-on": false,
          "separator-text": ":",
          "text-on": false,
          "text-font-family": {
            "family": "Arial"
          },
          "text-font-size": "24",
          "text-font-color": "#ffffff"
        }
      },
      "designId": 3,
      "theme": "white",
      "width": 488,
      "height": 147
    });
    if (_k != null) l.run();
  };
  _t.onload = _f;
  _t.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (_t.readyState == "loaded") _f(1);
  };
  var _h = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  _h.appendChild(_t);
}).call(this);
```

---

Я понял проблема в utc (всемирное время), но как его настраивать заказчику, если даже я пока не разобрался с ним? Только цыфры в коде utc меняю и так меняется время на сайте

Answer (score 0):

**Забавно**, что я тоже ищу ответ на этот вопрос.
Могу предложить попробовать создать новый счётчик на сайте, просто на нужную дату и из кода нового таймера скопировать нужную цифру utc и подставить в наш таймер.
Пока сам не пробовал, но по логике должно сработать

Answer (score 0):

https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/php - как все это работает

Мой код:

```
$new_date = date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
date_format($new_date, 'U'); // Format UNIX 1566382042
$second_date = (date_timestamp_get($new_date))*1000; // Format in secconds
```

Вам нужно то что выходит на $second_date, время окончание

```
$new_date = date_create(date("2019-08-21 12:00:00"));
```